# Symfony2 Sylius CartBundle setVariant method undefined

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I was looking for an ecommerce bundle and I found the SyliusEcommerce bundles. They are well documented and etc.. so I tried.

I installed the bundle, and based on the documentation `http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusCartBundle/installation.html.` You add a product with the setVariant method..

The problem is, this method is not even created. Doing a full scan of the sylius vendor folder in PhpStorm didnt find a single reference to it.. And there is no method like SetProduct, addProduct or etc... There are methods like SetQuantity and all, but I cant find the method for adding a product...

Anyone using these bundles maybe could explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. It was just a mistake in the documentation. It should be **setProduct** (CartItem's method) instead of **setVariant**.